# contact form 7 radio button checked

Tags: css, wordpress, radio-button

I want to stylize my radio buttons in a WP plugin ContactForm7, and I am using the source code from this website : [Source CSS code](http://cssdeck.com/labs/ldmtsmfk)

When radio button is clicked / checked it should become green:

```
.wpcf7 .wpcf7-list-item:checked .wpcf7-list-item-label:before{
    content:'\2714';
    text-indent: .9em;
    color: #9CE2AE;
    background-color: #4DCB6D;
}
```

what selectors do I use? how do I get to it?

Note: if I put 'active' instead of checked, then it flashes green when I press the mouse button...

I am lost! Thanks for help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go for :focus,

This should work.